# Using "OR" versus "AND" Operator for Getting Specific Results

Tags: sql-server-2008

Will do my best to explain my problem here.  I ran a query which works good for checking people who have completed either `courseIDNum=11` or `courseIDNum=12` in `districtIDNum=5`, but NOT both courseIDNums.  Here is the script:

```
SELECT max(p.FirstName),
   max(p.LastName),
   max(p.Email),
   max(s.CourseIDNum)
FROM People p
INNER JOIN Registration r
   on p.PeopleID = r.PeopleIdNum
INNER JOIN Section s
   on r.SectionIDNum = s.SectionID
INNER JOIN School sc
   on p.SchoolIDNum = sc.SchoolID
WHERE s.CourseIDNum IN (11, 12)
AND sc.DistrictIDNum = 5
AND r.Completed='Y'
group by p.PeopleID
having count(distinct s.CourseIDNum)=1
```

Now I am tasked to retrieve data for the people in `districtIDNum=5` again, but this time to check if they have taken all 3 courses, which 2 out of the 3 courses have the **same course name** but each of these 2 courses has 2 different courseIDNums.  So, I edited the `WHERE` portion shown below.  The results returned are only people who completed `12` and `177`, there is no result for `11`, `68` and `128`.  Then, I replaced the **OR** with the **AND** operator, and **0 rows** is returned.  Any help in this is much appreciated!

```
WHERE s.CourseIDNum IN (11, 12)
   OR s.CourseIDNum IN (68, 177)
   OR s.CourseIDNum=128
   AND sc.DistrictIDNum = 5
   AND r.Completed='Y'
group by p.PeopleID
having count(distinct s.CourseIDNum)=3
```

Here are the tables involved:

peopleID   FirstName   LastName   Email                     schoolIDNum
1               Esther         B                b@hotmail.com      33
2               Tommy        L                 l@hotmail.com       55
3               Liz               M                m@hotmail.com     90

registrationID   peopleIDNum   sectionIDNum
22                    1                      40
23                    2                      41
24                    3                      132
25                    1                      78
26                    2                      52
27                    1                      63

sectionID   courseIDNum
40              11
41              12
52              68
63              128
78              177
132            195

courseID   coursename
11             Health (Old)
12             Health (New)
68             PE (Old)
128           Keyboarding
177           PE (New)
195           Computing

schoolID   districtIDNum
33             5
55             5
90             12

Comment: AND is higher precedence than OR. So I *think* you should say `WHERE (x OR y) AND z` but I have no idea what results you're looking for. In this case, though, why not just `CourseIDNum IN (11,12,68,177,128)`?

Comment: @Aaron: I changed it to `CourseIDNum IN (11,12,68,177,128)`, it did give me people who completed these courses.  The only problem is it gave me other districts but I only need people from `districtIDNum=5`.  Please help, and thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't guess what your query looks like now. Please update your question and describe what is still wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include sample data, the output you're getting now, and the output you want to get instead from that data, so we can clearly understand what you're asking for help obtaining. Thanks.

Comment: @Esther: Have you tried: WHERE s.CourseIDNum IN (11, 12) AND sc.DistrictIDNum = 5

Comment: @Aaron: My bet. I forgot to change `(distinct s.CourseIDNum)=3` to `=1`.  Now it is returning all 3 courses with different courseIDNums for `districtIDNum=5`.  I do have one question - the comma (,) between the courseIDNum like `(11,12,68...)` - does it mean "OR"?

Comment: @Aaron: THANKS for the info! Actually, I need to know if people in `districtIDNum=5` have taken (11 or 12) AND (68 or 177) AND 128.  I will post more sample data in a little bit.

Comment: Yes sample data and desired results are about 10000% more useful than "here is the query I tried and it didn't work."

Comment: Just posted sample data for your review.  As you can see, `11` and `12` are actually the same course, only with <strong>different</strong> courseIDNums.  Same with `68` and `177`.  The results I'd like to get are the firstname, lastname, and email of people in `districtIDNum=5` to see who have completed ALL 3 courses: `Health`, `PE` and `Keyboarding`.  Because `Health` has 2 different IDs, meaning the folks will either take `11` or `12`, not both.  Same goes for `PE`: `68` or `177`, except for `128`.  I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Aaron: Please see data posted above.  Thank you.

Comment: Try `WHERE CourseIDNum IN (11, 12) AND CourseIDNum IN (68 or 177) AND CourseIDNum = 128 AND districtIDNum=5`

Comment: @Nikita CourseIDNum can't be both (11 or 12) *and* (68 or 177) at the same time. I'm still waiting for the OP to post desired results so we can better understand what actually should be returned. Esther it would also be a good idea to include, in your sample data, some rows that *should NOT* be returned.

Comment: Righ, I apologize, not sure what I was thinking...

Comment: @Aaron: Added rows that should NOT be returned, such as `Liz M` from `districtIDNum=12` who completed `courseIDNum=195`.  On the hand, Esther B from `districtIDNum=5` has completed courseIDs `11, 177 and 128`; therefore, her firstname, lastname, email, along with the courseIDs should show in return.  The results should also show that Tommy L from `districtIDNum=5` has completed courseIDs `12 and 68`.  I truly thank you for your help!

Comment: @Aaron: Please help if you have time.  Thanks!